# BouncyCastle sign in PHP/OpenSSL

Tags: php, linux, openssl, bouncycastle, sign

I want to sign content with OpenSSL in PHP (or cli linux OpenSSL). Signatures generated by BouncyCastle in Java:

```
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(tokenToSignBytes);
        SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);


        CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(signerCert);

        signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, false);

        return signedCms.Encode("DER");
```

Gives other result than `openssl_sign();` in PHP or openssl via command line.

**How to generate same signature as bouncycastle generates but in PHP/cli?**

Thanks
Leo

Comment: Do you have the implementation in PHp? I need it desperatly

Answer (score 0):

openssl_sign computes binary signature, while you need PKCS#7 one.
You should use the function openssl_pkcs7_sign instead.